# Css not reflecting in sitecore modal window

Tags: sxa, css

I am opening a modal window using

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SearchModal", "Myctrler",new { id =itemVal })"
                                   onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("SearchModal", "Myctrler",new { id = itemVal })',
                      'newwindow',
                      'width=300,height=250');
                                                        return false;">
```

In the My contoller i am returning Searchview  using

```
public ActionResult SearchModal(string id)
        {
            ModalData msd = repository.getData(id);
            return View(msd);
        }
```

But none of the css is reflecting from sitecore in the view .Can anyone pls suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have the code setup, you are bypassing Sitecore and just rendering an MVC View using `@Url.Action` in a new window. If you want to take that approach, you would need to add a reference to the stylesheet in your view.

A better approach would be to build a JavaScript based modal that would then have the markup inline and pick up the styles of the site. Have a look at existing modals like the Bootstrap Modal that works in this way.